# Spring WebClient is not using the proxy server with spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, proxy

I have to migrate an existing `OAuth2RestTemplate` based OAuth2 microservice to Spring Security / `WebClient` because `OAuth2RestTemplate` is deprecated. However, the new implementation is unable to access the OAuth2 server through a proxy server. I've read various articles on this topic, including [Spring WebClient is not using Proxy for the latest version of spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8966), and tried to include the logic described in these articles in my implementation. Without success unfortunately. My implementation configures the underlying `ClientHttpConnector` used by `WebClient` with the appropriate proxy settings. See the code snippets below from `WebClientConfig` (the complete codebase including `WebClientConfig`and unit tests can be found here: [github](https://github.com/easyRider651/proxy-server-test)):

```
  @Bean
  public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
    ClientRegistration clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
        .withRegistrationId(REGISTRATION_ID)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
        .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
        .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST)
        .userInfoAuthenticationMethod(AuthenticationMethod.FORM)
        .tokenUri(restServiceProperties.getOauth2Url())
        .build();
    return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
  }
```

```
  @Bean
  public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
    return new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
  }
```

```
  @Bean
  public ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector() {
    HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom();
    if (Strings.isNotEmpty(restServiceProperties.getProxyUrl())) {
      try {
        HttpHost proxy = HttpHost.create(restServiceProperties.getProxyUrl());
        clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy));
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        log.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = clientBuilder.build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(client);
  }
```

```
  @Bean
  public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
      ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService, ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector, WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

    WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder
        .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
        .filter(logRequest())
        .build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(createAuthorizedClientProvider(webClient));
    authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(request -> {
      Map<String, Object> contextAttributes = new HashMap<>();
      contextAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, USER);
      contextAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, PASSWORD);
      return Mono.just(contextAttributes);
    });

    return authorizedClientManager;
  }
```

```
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager,
      ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector, WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2FilterFunction = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2FilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(REGISTRATION_ID);

    return webClientBuilder
        .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
        .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
          exchangeFilterFunctions.add(oauth2FilterFunction);
          exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
        })
        .build();
  }
```

```
  private ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider createAuthorizedClientProvider(WebClient webClient) {
    WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient clientCredentialsTokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
    clientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.setWebClient(webClient);
    return ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
        .clientCredentials(builder -> builder.accessTokenResponseClient(clientCredentialsTokenResponseClient))
        .password()
        .refreshToken()
        .build();
  }
```

```
  private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
      log.info("Request: method: {} URL: {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
      clientRequest.headers().forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> log.info("Request header: name: {} value: {}", name, value)));
      return Mono.just(clientRequest);
    });
  }
```

I also tried `clientBuilder.setProxy(proxy)` rather than `clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy))`, but that didn't solve the issue.

Regardig the unit tests: `NoProxyServerTest` shows that the OAuth2 server and downstream server can be accessed when no proxy server is configured. `ProxyServerTest` shows that the OAuth2 server cannot be accessed when a proxy server is configured. `DirectProxyServerInvocationTest` shows that the `MockProxyServer` is actually working. And `DownstreamServerProxyServerInvocationTest` shows that the downstream server can accessed through a proxy server. `WebClient` is configured in `WebClientConfig`. This is potentially the best configuration so far, but I've tried many different configurations to solve this proxy server issue (including the use of `https.proxyPort`, `https.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`and `http.proxyHost`).

A similar test approached is being used to test the deprecated OAuth2RestTemplate based implementation. And all four tests pass against that implementation.

Comment: Hi, I have also run into the same issue. Have you fixed this issue? Please share, stuck with this issue for days now.....thank you!